# Log4Net with SQLite is throwing a Format Exception

Tags: c#, sqlite, logging

I am trying to use Log4Net and log my messages to a local SQLite DB. However when I run the application a Format Exception is thrown in `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();`

Here is my config file:

```
<log4net>
```

```
<appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender" >
  <file value="log-file.txt" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />

  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%-5level] - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="DebugAppender" type="log4net.Appender.DebugAppender">
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%-5level] - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>


<appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
  <bufferSize value="0" />
  <connectionType value="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection, System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.77.0" />
  <connectionString value="Data Source=.\kapiti.db;Version=3;" />
  <commandText value="INSERT INTO Log (Date, Level, Logger, Message) VALUES (@Date, @Level, @Logger, @Message)" />
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@Date" />
    <dbType value="DateTime" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@Level" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%level" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@Logger" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@Message" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%message" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
</appender>

<!-- Setup the root category, add the appenders
       and set the default level -->
<root>
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="DebugAppender" />
  <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
  <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
</root>
```

The Table is created like this, and has this schema :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Log;
CREATE TABLE Log (
    LogId     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Date      DATETIME NOT NULL,
    Level     VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Logger    VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Message   TEXT DEFAULT NULL
    RowVersion INTEGER DEFAULT 1
);

CREATE TRIGGER Log_rowversion_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON Log 
BEGIN
UPDATE Log SET RowVersion = new.RowVersion + 1  WHERE Id = new.Id;
END;
```

Please Let me know if you can see where I made the error, I have been stuck on this all day.

Thank you
RF

STACK TRACE:

```
mscorlib.dll!long.Parse(string s = "DateTime", System.Globalization.NumberStyles style = AllowLeadingWhite | AllowTrailingWhite | AllowLeadingSign, System.IFormatProvider provider = {System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo}) + 0x1a bytes 
mscorlib.dll!System.Convert.ToInt64(string value = "DateTime", System.IFormatProvider provider = {}) + 0x13 bytes   
mscorlib.dll!string.System.IConvertible.ToInt64(System.IFormatProvider provider = {}) + 0x7 bytes   
mscorlib.dll!System.Convert.DefaultToType(System.IConvertible value = "DateTime", System.Type targetType = {Name = "Int64" FullName = "System.Int64"}, System.IFormatProvider provider = {}) + 0xe5 bytes   
mscorlib.dll!string.System.IConvertible.ToType(System.Type type = {Name = "Int64" FullName = "System.Int64"}, System.IFormatProvider provider = {}) 
mscorlib.dll!System.Convert.ChangeType(object value = "DateTime", System.Type conversionType = {Name = "Int64" FullName = "System.Int64"}, System.IFormatProvider provider = {}) + 0x51 bytes   
log4net.dll!log4net.Util.OptionConverter.ParseEnum(System.Type enumType = {Name = "DbType" FullName = "System.Data.DbType"}, string value = "DateTime", bool ignoreCase = true) + 0x4d bytes    
log4net.dll!log4net.Util.OptionConverter.ConvertStringTo(System.Type target = {Name = "DbType" FullName = "System.Data.DbType"}, string txt = "DateTime") + 0x5d bytes  
log4net.dll!log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.ConvertStringTo(System.Type type = {Name = "DbType" FullName = "System.Data.DbType"}, string value = "DateTime") + 0x41 bytes 
log4net.dll!log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.SetParameter(System.Xml.XmlElement element = {System.Xml.XmlElement}, object target = {log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter}) + 0x282 bytes   
log4net.dll!log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.CreateObjectFromXml(System.Xml.XmlElement element = {System.Xml.XmlElement}, System.Type defaultTargetType = {Name = "AdoNetAppenderParameter" FullName = "log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter"}, System.Type typeConstraint = {Name = "AdoNetAppenderParameter" FullName = "log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter"}) + 0x13a bytes   
log4net.dll!log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.SetParameter(System.Xml.XmlElement element = {System.Xml.XmlElement}, object target = {log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender}) + 0x525 bytes    
log4net.dll!log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.ParseAppender(System.Xml.XmlElement appenderElement = {System.Xml.XmlElement}) + 0x170 bytes  
log4net.dll!log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.FindAppenderByReference(System.Xml.XmlElement appenderRef = {System.Xml.XmlElement}) + 0xb1 bytes 
log4net.dll!log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.ParseChildrenOfLoggerElement(System.Xml.XmlElement catElement = {System.Xml.XmlElement}, log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger log = {log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.RootLogger}, bool isRoot = true) + 0x4a bytes    
log4net.dll!log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.ParseRoot(System.Xml.XmlElement rootElement = {System.Xml.XmlElement}) + 0x1d bytes   
log4net.dll!log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.Configure(System.Xml.XmlElement element = {System.Xml.XmlElement}) + 0x1e1 bytes  
log4net.dll!log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy.XmlRepositoryConfigure(System.Xml.XmlElement element = {System.Xml.XmlElement}) + 0xe bytes  
log4net.dll!log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy.log4net.Repository.IXmlRepositoryConfigurator.Configure(System.Xml.XmlElement element = {System.Xml.XmlElement}) + 0x7 bytes 
log4net.dll!log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureFromXml(log4net.Repository.ILoggerRepository repository = {log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy}, System.Xml.XmlElement element = {System.Xml.XmlElement}) + 0x7a bytes   
log4net.dll!log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(log4net.Repository.ILoggerRepository repository = {log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy}, System.IO.Stream configStream = {System.IO.FileStream}) + 0xbb bytes   
log4net.dll!log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(log4net.Repository.ILoggerRepository repository = {log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy}, System.IO.FileInfo configFile = {\Program Files\AlliedPetroleum.Client\AlliedPetroleum.Client.exe.config}) + 0xa7 bytes    
log4net.dll!log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(log4net.Repository.ILoggerRepository repository = {log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy}) + 0x52 bytes
```

> log4net.dll!log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure() + 0xf bytes AlliedPetroleum.Client.exe!AlliedPetroleum.Client.Program.Main() Line 47 + 0x5 bytes C#

Comment: What's the line of code that's throwing the FormatException?

Comment: Hi Brenda,
The Exception is thrown at : log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

Comment: I think its in the AdoNetAppender to be more precise

Comment: The exception really contains no exception message?  Because just telling us the exception type isn't enough to go on.

Comment: Sorry, thats all that came up when I ran it. I can't seem to figure it out. From what you can see, is there anything obviously wrong with the AdoNetAppender appender? The error definitely occurs in there. Am I perhaps missing something?

Comment: Well, at least provide the full stack trace then.

Comment: Ah. I'm not all that familiar with logging to a database, but if I had to make an educated guess I'd say there's an issue with the value being bound to the date field (or the way it's being formatted).

Maybe try enabling log4net debugging to see if there's more information?

Comment: The irony of using log4net to log log4net logs :) Thanks you, I will give it a go and let you know the outcome